# Understanding why $|\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)| \leq \max \{\operatorname{var}(X), \operatorname{var}(Y) \}$ for two random variables $X, Y$

Tags: statistics

Supposing that I have two random variables $X,Y$, I encounter the inequality that
$|\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)| \leq \max \{\operatorname{var}(X), \operatorname{var}(Y) \}$.

So if $X,Y$ are uncorrelated, i.e. $\operatorname{cov}(X, Y)$ is $0$, then since variance is always non-negative the result follows.

If $X,Y$ are negatively correlated, i.e. $\operatorname{cov}(X, Y) < 0$, then again the result follows since variance is always non-negative.

Now if $X, Y$ are positively correlated, say $\operatorname{cov} (X, Y) = K$ for some $K \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$. I want to understand why $K \leq \max \{\operatorname{var}(X), \operatorname{var}(Y) $.

I have to use max, rather than min, since in this post [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134819/covariance-greater-than-variance) a counter-example is given, where you can suppose that $X$ has variance $6^2$, $Y$ has variance $8^2$, and the correlation coefficient is $\frac{5}{6}$ where $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y) = \frac{5}{6} * 6 * 8 = 40 > \min (\operatorname{var}(X), \operatorname{var}(Y)) = 36$.

Any insights appreciated.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz gives $\lvert\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)\rvert \leq [\operatorname{Var}(X)]^{1/2}[\operatorname{Var}(Y)]^{1/2}$ and each of $\operatorname{Var}(X),\operatorname{Var}(Y)$ is bounded by their maximum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, and the fact that the arithmetic mean is greater than or equal to the geometric mean
$\newcommand{\cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}$
$\newcommand{\var}{\operatorname{Var}}$

$$\cov(X,Y) \leq \sqrt{\var(X)}\sqrt{\var(Y)} \leq \frac{\var(X) + \var(Y)}{2} \leq \max\{{\var(X),\var(Y)}\}$$